# org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, wordpress-rest-api

```
``@PostMapping(value = "/staff/saveStaff" , consumes=MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public String saveStaff(@RequestPart("staff") Staff staff,@RequestPart("profilePic") MultipartFile profilePic) {

    logger.debug(" Staff "+staff+":"+profilePic);
    return null;

}`
```

Want to post Json object and MultipartFile in one request, tried @ModelAttribute instead of @RequestPart so received file object, but Staff object is null.

Tried to change Media type but did not worked, removed media type still not working,

Http request in React js: using Axios

```
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("profilePic",this.state.profilePic)
      formData.append("staff",{...this.state.staff})
      axios.post("/staff/saveStaff", 
        formData,
       {headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
         }}
        )
          .then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
              console.log("Saved");                 

            }
          })
```

Comment: Could you show us the HTTP request that you are making? (curl, Postman or other) With the header you are giving as well please?

Comment: Added HTTP call from react js using axios

Comment: Thanks, can you try to change your axios header to 'Content-Type': 'application/json' please?

Comment: Nope! not worked out :(